# Android : Only one button clickable at once

Tags: android, events, button, onclick

While developing an android app, I have an activity with some buttons. I would like the `onClickListener` action to start when the user puts his finger on the screen immediately so he isn't able to click two buttons at once.

I do that in iOS by using the `touchDown` event rather than the default `TouchUpInside.`

I have absolutely no idea of how this can be done in Android...

Android code :

```
button.setOnClickListener(clicked);

[...]


View.OnClickListener clicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

//Cool stuff there

}
}
```

thanks for helping !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is using an [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) instead of the OnClickListener. This will allow you to react upon the first touch of the button and stop reacting on other button touches until the first touch is stopped again.

Comment: Thank you ! As some buttons are not supposed to be clickable, i've put the code under OnTouch(view v, motion m) under the if(v.isClickable()) condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the other buttons when you start the click and re-enable them when you are finished.

By default the buttons clicks will be handled on the same thread so their actions would not complete in parallel even if you do not disable them.

Comment: I tried that but the onClick event starts when you release your finger only that didn't work for me. @FD_ solution worked fine. Thank you anyway !